# Quick question about ln(0)

Tags: calculus

When integrating

$$\int_{0}^{1}\ln x\,\mathrm dx=\ln(1)-1 - 0(\ln(0)-0) = -1-0\ln(0)$$

and so the integral should be indeterminate because $0\ln(0)$ is indeterminate, right?)

Comment: this is an improper integral; you should take the limit

Comment: Indeterminate is not an answer. Indeterminate is a way of saying that more computations are needed.

Comment: You could also side step the indeterminate form by solving the equivalent integral down the $y$ axis.  $\int_{0}^{1}\ln x\,\mathrm dx=\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^y\,\mathrm dy = -1$

Comment: You know about L'Hôpital's rule right?  Just put the indeterminate form into $\infty/\infty$ form as follows $x \ln x = \frac{\ln x}{1/x}$.  Then take derivatives.  It is pretty straight forward.

Comment: @Rousseau, your first equality is not permitted; it is an improper integral but your treated is as a definite integral.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_0^1 \ln(x) dx = \underset{a\rightarrow 0^+}{\lim} \int_a^1 \ln(x) dx = \underset{a\rightarrow 0^+}{\lim} [x\ln(x) - x]_a^1 = \underset{a\rightarrow 0^+}{\lim} -1 - a\ln(a) = -1 - 0 = -1$$

Comment: I changed the limits to right-sided limits.

Answer (score 1):

By part,
$$\int_{0^+}^1\ln(x)dx=\big[x\ln x\big]_{0^+}^1-\int_0^1dx=0-\underbrace{\lim_{x\to 0^+}(x\ln x)}_{=0}-1=-1.$$